# Declaring MySql command

Tags: c#, mysql, scope, declaration

I was wondering about something. Lets say I have this piece of code:

```
if (cbBackup.Checked)
{
    log("Making backup, this might take a while..");

    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(GetFromResources("databaseInstaller.qry.backup.sql"), conn);
}

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(GetFromResources("databaseInstaller.qry.anotherfile.sql"), conn);
```

The problem with this is, I cannot make comm again, because it's already been made. But the code might not reach that part if cbBackup is not checked.

Can I just re-declare the value of comm, even if the program doesn't get past the IF function? -or should I just make another SqlCommand?

Any other suggestion is welcome, ofcourse.

Edit: It's not a matter of if-else. One of them always executes, the other one only executes if cbBackup is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SqlCommand comm;
if (cbBackup.Checked)
{
    log("Making backup, this might take a while..");

    comm = new SqlCommand(GetFromResources("databaseInstaller.qry.osrose_backup.sql"), conn);
} 

comm = new SqlCommand(GetFromResources("databaseInstaller.qry.anotherfile.sql"), conn);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not a matter of if-else. One of them executes always, the other one only executes if cbBackup is checked. Edit: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand comm;
if (cbBackup.Checked)
{
    log("Making backup, this might take a while..");

    comm = new SqlCommand(GetFromResources("databaseInstaller.qry.osrose_backup.sql"), conn);
}
else
{
    comm = new SqlCommand(GetFromResources("databaseInstaller.qry.anotherfile.sql"), conn);
}
```